# Convergence in the final topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a set. Let $(Y_n,\tau_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ sequence of topological spaces. Let $Y_n$ be an increasing cover of $Y$ (i.e. $\cup_n Y_n =Y$ and $Y_n\subseteq Y_{n+1}\subseteq Y$). The topology $\tau$ on $Y$ is defined as:
$$A \in \tau \iff A \cap Y_n \in \tau_n \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.  $$

Let $\{y_n\}\subset Y$, $y\in Y$. Is it true that $y_n \to y$ in $\tau$ if and only if $\{y_n\}\subset Y_N$ (for a suitable $N\in \mathbb{N}$) and $y_n\to y$ in $\tau_N$ ?

If not, what is an additional assumption in order to have this property ?

Up to now I have proved only the implication "$\Leftarrow$".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It’s true if the spaces are $T_1$. Suppose that this is the case, and let $\langle y_n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $Y$ that is not contained in any $Y_n$. By passing to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $\{n\in\Bbb N:y_n\in Y_k\}$ is finite for each $k\in\Bbb N$. If $S=\{y_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, then $S\cap Y_n$ is finite for each $n\in\Bbb N$. But then $S\cap Y_n$ is closed in $Y_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $S$ is closed in $Y$, and since $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is not eventually constant, it cannot be convergent.